# WeakReference in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Activity starts AsyncTask and after it done, this task needs to check if this activity is destroyed and garbage collected. I thought that WeakReference help me to solve this question. But even if i rotate screen and activity is destroyed, i still not null. What i do wrong?

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

WeakReference<ActivitySecond> sactivity;
MyAsyncTask(ActivitySecond a)
{
    sactivity = new WeakReference<>(a);
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    finally {
        return "Ok";
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    if (sactivity!=null)
    {
        ActivitySecond activity =    sactivity.get();
        if (activity!=null)
            Toast.makeText(activity,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it is destroyed but not gc-ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no other reference to the object apart from the weak reference, the object is allowed to be garbage collected.

But no guarantee is made when this is actually done.

Comment: 1.This code is right? 2. What i can do to wait till GC performs?

Comment: The usage of the WeakReference looks 'ok'. You set it in the constructor (I would make sactivity final). And you do a null check before using the reference to the object. You don't need to do a nullcheck on sactivity; unless you are explicitly nulling it. But I don't know what else is going on.

At some point the GC will garbage collect that object and set the reference in the WeakReference to null. You just can't force it to happen.

Comment: I found another example. When i load large image in ImageView GC remove activity  when i rotate screen. You comment in enough. Thank you!